# Javascript to change background colour and font size

Tags: javascript, html

```
input type="button" name="colr" value=" Blue " onclick="document.bgColor='#0000FF'"
```

Basically i have done buttons using javascipt to change the background colour in my website preferences, but when the page is refeshed it goes back to what it is in the css, is there anyway i can get it to stay without using cookies?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You would need to change your design approach.

If the button is to have a fixed color, you should use predefined CSS for the button instead of changing it using JavaScript.

Comment: the question was how to change and KEEP the bgcolor of the site, not the button