# Change Header Background Colour with Button

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

I am have created a custom theme for my [tumblr](http://theory-yes-reality-no.tumblr.com/fish) blog. I am trying to add a button that will change the colour of my header background for end users. I would just like 3 buttons for `blue(#4BD4DE)`, `red(red)` and `green(#1FDE2C)`. I have a limited understanding of Javascript. I have used `<button>` and `<input>`. What i have tried so far, `

```
<script>
$("btnBlue").on("click", function() {
  document.header.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
</script>`
```

But this does nothing. Any help? I have checked other questions on stack overflow but none worked, and I don't have enough knowledge to change the posted code.

Code i am using relevant to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<!-- CSS Style -->

<style>
header {
    background: #4BD4DE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>

<!-- Tumblr styling here -->

<!-- BUTTONS -->
<button class="btnBlue">Change Colour</button> <button class="btnRed">Change      Colour</button> <button class="btnGreen">Change Colour</button>


<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
$("btnBlue").on("click", function() {
  document.header.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: None of the code apears to be working, maybe a tumblr problem... but it tumbr apears to support javascript. If anyone out there is a tumblr theme writer then, would it work, any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565696/javascript-to-change-background-colour-and-font-size?rq=1

Comment: You better start learning some JavaScript and try something first ;-).

Comment: this is not the way to ask a quetion,at least post your markup of the header and buttons...the solution is simple..but you must give sufficient details

Comment: Choosing the colors is a good first step. Now you'll want to hire a web developer to do the rest.

Comment: @SajadLfc If you click on the link the zip for the code for the theme is available to view.

Comment: @DanO I have checked but none of those seemed to work for me.

Comment: @putvande i am 13, i have been do very basic HTML for 1 year and i ahev only just started learning properly

Comment: @nullability I'm 13, the aim of me asking here is to help me get better at HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want help with your code please add it to your question.

Comment: For sanity, JavaScript / jQuery works fine within Tumblr themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple just use three buttons to pass the color you want into the function that changes the background. I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="header">Header</h1>
<input type="button" value="Blue" onclick="color('#4BD4DE')">
<input type="button" value="Red" onclick="color('red')">
<input type="button" value="Green" onclick="color('#1FDE2C')">
<script>

function color(col){
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor=col;

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the code worked fine on a test webpage but it didn't work on my tumblr theme, any suggentions??

Comment: Have you tried adding the exact code, It will only work if the header has an id of "header"

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("button").click(function () {
      $("h1").css("background-color", "blue");
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wud22/

Extension to what you want to do should be obvious, I hope. Uses jQuery.

To include jQuery you need to add this line to your header:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine on a test but it wont work on tumblr, maybe its not possible... thanks

Comment: make sure that you have included jQuery. See edit above.

Comment: It's definintely possible within tumblr. You might need to post a link to your tumblr site.